# Scheduled task fails to run, no error code

Tags: windows, permissions, scheduled-tasks

We're using a scheduled task to run a simple executable every 2 minutes, it has a working directory set (no quotes round the path) but other than that most options are left as defaults.

Running the task manually by right-clicking on it and selecting Run works just fine, however it never executes automatically.  When the time comes to run the task, it just increments the "Next Run Time" field by 2 minutes and that's it.  The Last Run Time Field is always the last time the task was manually executed.

The Last Run Result is always 0x0.

I've tried setting it to run as the current user, or as an alternate user set up with administrative privileges and a stored password, but still no luck.

There doesn't appear to be anything immediately obvious in the system event log either to indicate the cause of the failure.

As a bit of background, this is a headless Win10 Pro machine (only ever accessed via LogMeIn) running control software for external hardware.  It reboots every morning at 03:00 and since it's on an physically isolated network, automatically logs in to a user account with administrative privileges and no password.

I suspect it may be a permissions issue with the insecure way the system is set up, however at this point there's little to go on.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity, this turned out to be an issue with the way the repetition on the scheduled task was set up.  Initially it was set up as a daily task to run every 2 minutes for 24 hours.  Whilst this showed the correct next run time in the task scheduler window, for some reason it never executed - Bug?

The fix was instead to set the task up as a one time event that repeats every 2 minutes indefinitely, which seems to be working properly now.